# google apps script and GmailApp: get just new messages

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm trying to implement a simple google script that processes each message that is received by a Gmail user.

I've found an example that does something like this:

```
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
for (var i=0; i < threads.length; i++) {
   var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

   for (var j=0; j < messages.length; j++) {
       if (!messages[j].isUnread()) {
         continue; 
       }
      //process message
   }
}
```

That is: I iterate through all messages in the inbox and search for the unread ones. This is very slow on just 1800 messages.

Ideally, I'm looking for a trigger that gets fired once each new message is received.

If there is no such thing, I would try to make use of this that I saw:

```
GmailApp.getMessageById(id)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry for the late response but I just had the same type of problem and I ended up using GmailApp.search() ... hope this helps.

```
// find unread messages
var threads = GmailApp.search('is:unread');
....
```

**WARNING**

> This call will fail when the size of all threads is too large for the system to handle. Where the thread size is unknown, and potentially very large, please use the 'paged' call, and specify ranges of the threads to retrieve in each call.

Take a look at [GmailApp.search(query)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String)) and
[GmailApp.search(query, start, max)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String,Integer,Integer))

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately there in no trigger that fires for each recieved message. There is however a good workaround:

Set up a filter rule that assigns a special label, "ToBeProcessedByScript" as example, to all incoming messages. Since wildcards don't really work in Gmail filters use the to: field.

Run a time-triggered script that collects all new message threads with `GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("ToBeProcessedByScript").getThreads()`. Remove the special label just before processing the new messages.

Comment: A slight problem with this approach: labels are attached to threads, not messages. This means that as a message comes in to the inbox and is added to an existing thread which has already been processed the label will be reapplied to the thread and your approach would process every message in the thread again.

This can be avoided by identifying which messages not to reprocess: 

**quick and dirty:** star the messages and only process unstarred ones
**slow and thorough:** record the message ids somewhere and check for duplicates before/during/after processing

Answer (score 4):

you can use

```
GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 50);
```

to initialize the variable with first fifty mail.

Answer (score 3):

I have extended the code with checking if the first message is really the one which is unread. If it is not it will check the next message and will continue untill it finds the unread message:

```
function getUnreadMails() {
   var ureadMsgsCount = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();
   var threads;
   var messages;
   var k=1;
   if(ureadMsgsCount>0)
   {        
     threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, ureadMsgsCount);
     for(var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
     {
       if(threads[i].isInInbox())
       {
          messages = threads[i].getMessages();
          for(var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
          {

             while (messages[j].isUnread() === false)
             {
             threads=GmailApp.getInboxThreads(k, ureadMsgsCount);
             messages = threads[i].getMessages();
             k++;
             }
             Logger.log(messages[j].getSubject());

             // process unread message
          }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a time trigger as djtek mentioned but instead of labeling all messages and then retrieve labeled messages, you can just get the number of the unread messages, and retrieve threads from 0 to the number of the unread messages, following a code that works for me:

```
 function getUnreadMails() {
   var ureadMsgsCount = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount()
   if(ureadMsgsCount>0)
   {        
     var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, ureadMsgsCount);
     for(var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
     {
       if(threads[i].isInInbox())
       {
          var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
          for(var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
          {
             Logger.log(messages[j].getSubject());
             // process unread message
          }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: replaced `length()` with `length`

Comment: This will only work if all of the unread emails are at the top of the inbox.  If the user has read an email in the middle, then it'll miss unread emails at the bottom of the list and try to process any read emails above them.  Given how slow apps script is when processing email threads, it is probably unreasonable to assume that this script will run quickly enough to catch all emails before a user reads them.  Now, if the gmail account is never read by a user, and is only processed automatically, it's fine, but the OP doesn't explicitly specify that this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getUnreadMessages(threadLimit) {
  function flatten(arr) { return [].concat.apply([], arr) }
  var threadsWithUnreadMessages = GmailApp.search('is:unread', 0, threadLimit)
  var messageCollection = threadsWithUnreadMessages.map(function(thread) {
    return thread.getMessages()
  })
  var unreadMessages = flatten(messageCollection).filter(function(message) { 
    return message.isUnread()
  })
  return unreadMessages
}

getUnreadMessages(100)
```